# Group By and Last Qry in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
"idx"   "date"  "time"  "HomeMatchingId"    "HomeName"  "AwayMatchingId"    "awayname"  "FTOU"  "FTOverOdds"    "FTUnderOdds"   "sportsbook"
"137859"    "20121220"  "16:00:05"  "811"   "Mersin Idmanyurdu" "365"   "Antalyaspor"   "2.5"   "-0.89" "0.79"  "IBCBet"
"137858"    "20121220"  "16:00:05"  "811"   "Mersin Idmanyurdu" "365"   "Antalyaspor"   "2-2.5" "0.84"  "-0.94" "IBCBet"
"137767"    "20121220"  "15:59:50"  "811"   "Mersin Idmanyurdu" "365"   "Antalyaspor"   "2.5"   "-0.89" "0.79"  "IBCBet"
"137766"    "20121220"  "15:59:50"  "811"   "Mersin Idmanyurdu" "365"   "Antalyaspor"   "2-2.5" "0.84"  "-0.94" "IBCBet"
"137607"    "20121220"  "15:59:02"  "811"   "Mersin Idmanyurdu" "365"   "Antalyaspor"   "2-2.5" "0.87"  "-0.97" "IBCBet"
```

Based upon the above data, I am trying to retrieve the last print for each FTOU, grouped by home and away matching ids (you only see one game here), and by FTOU and by SPortsbook. It is essentially the max idx for the group by qry.

This will give me the last price row for each handicap (FTOU), for each sportsbook, for each game.

In access I can use the 'last' qry, but no such luck in mysql.

Comment: not formatted too well, can I attach a file?

Comment: Can you add the query that you tried?

Comment: i normally build in access using the gui, but since the db is too large i have to do in mysql and it is a bit beyond my capabilities. i have reviewed other solutions to similar qrys but cannot seem to get it to fit for this.

Comment: i did have a solution, using DISTINCT ROW, but it was returning any old row, rather than max(idx)